# How to run a .Net Core webapplication on a Windows 7 machine?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to run a ASP.Net Core webapplication on a Windows 7 machine without having to install Visual Studio.

Can I just install .Net Core on the production environment or are there some preconditions that have to be met prior to installing .Net Core?

Comment: You can use the full .NET Core SDK without any Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried out some scenarios and I found out the following:

For running .Net Core you only need the .Net Core runtime (or the SDK) installed on the production environment. You can find the downloads here: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archive.md

For ASP.Net Core, which uses Kestrel for hosting, you only need the runtime (or the SDK) as well. (I tested this on Windows 7 and Linux Debian)
When hosting with IIS, see Andre.Santarosa answer

Answer (score 3):

Prior to run .NET Core on windows 7, your system must have SP1 and Hotfix KB2533623 insalled, install IIS package via Control Panel then DotNetCore WindowsHosting (this allow IIS to handle ASP.NET Core requests) - Link: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=827547

When you create your IIS application, it will create an application pool, set .NET CLR in this pool to "No Managed Code".

This should be enough you to run